# How to say if an error is not new?

Tags: grammar

I want to say that a specific error is not new, and has been there in the past. Here is how I would say it:

> This error was there before.

It feels to me like this is not how a native English speaker would say it. What would be a better phrasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are speaking about a *software* error, it is more common to refer to the inherent problem in the code as a "bug" and the resultant problem it produces as an "error". A bug is there whether it emerges or not, but an error is only seen if the bug is exploited. Check which you mean to say.

If the error/bug were still there, I would probably say:

> It **is** an **existing** error/bug.

Or, a common expression in the software industry for a bug that programmers/users are already aware of but has not yet been fixed is:

> It is a *known* bug.